# graph of function is connected for any closed interval $[k,k+1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

**Lemma**. Let $g\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $g\restriction [k,k+1]$ is connected subset of $\Bbb R^2$, means the graph of $g\restriction [k,k+1]$, for any integer $k.$ Then $g$ has a connected graph.

**Proof.** Notice that $g\restriction[-k,k]$ has a connected graph because $$g\restriction [-k,k] =\bigcup_{i=-k}^{k} g\restriction [i,i+1]$$ finite union of connected sets  each of two successive sets has nonempty intersection. Now, the graph of $g$ can be written as $$g=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} g\restriction [-k,k]$$  Then $g$ has a connected graph for the same reason. Is that true ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your proof looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: @RobArthan, Thank you for taking to time to read my proof.